# php echo file_get_contents from a01.txt to a36.tx

Tags: php

I am calling the content of 36 files to be rendered. The script works well, but I am wondering what would be a shorter way to do it. My code:

`<?php $arrays = file_get_contents('a01.txt');  echo $arrays;?>
<?php $arrays = file_get_contents('a02.txt');  echo $arrays;?>
<?php $arrays = file_get_contents('a03.txt');  echo $arrays;?>
<?php $arrays = file_get_contents('a04.txt');  echo $arrays;?>`

... X 36 untill ('a36.txt')

something like

`<?php $arrays = file_get_contents('a04.txt-a36.txt');  echo $arrays;?>`

Comment: With a `foreach` loop

Answer (score 0):

Use a loop

```
<?php 
for($i = 1; $i<=36; $i++) {
    // Add a zero before single digits
    $filename = 'a' . str_pad($i, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT) . '.txt';
    $content = file_get_contents($filename);  
    echo $content;
}
?>
```

http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-pad.php